# jQuery .live() + Date Picker + Pretty Photo fails to trigger in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following in my application

- DatePicker from jQuery UI
- Pretty Photo.

When I press some link a PrettyPhoto popup opens with a input field which should trigger the DatePicker.

I managed to make the DatePicker work correctly with this piece of code:

```
$(function(){ 

    $('#date_pp').live('click',function (){
        $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker().focus();
    });
});
```

Now everything work just fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer.
I'm just guessing that IE has some problem with the `.live()` method because it fails to run even a dummy alert message. Weirdly enough the jQuery examples from their official website work.

Over [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/10/14/how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery.html) I red something about this issue and tried their method. This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the *problem*.

Following the jQuery tutorial I placed the datepicker js code in the same file with the field which triggers the datepicker. This file was dynamically inserted in the DOM with PrettyPhoto.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#date_pp').live('click',function (){
        $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker().focus();
    });
});
```

I removed this code from the file above mentioned and rewrote it in a separate `.js` file. Then I simply declared the code in the parent document's (the in which all this happens) header:

```
<script src="js/action.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now everything works just fine in all browsers including IE

Answer (score 1):

Define datepicker outside of click function and use doucment ready,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) 
{
      $('#date_pp').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: This won't work on any browser. The reason is that the input which triggers the DatePicker is dynamically inserted with the Pretty Photo. This is why there is need for that `.live()` method